# Как заблокировать виджет Text в tkinter python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как заблокировать виджет `Text` в tkinter, чтобы пользователь не мог писать, а программа могла добавлять текст?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно создать виджет `Text` заблокированным (`state=DISABLED`), а потом при каждом выводе временно разблокировать его, выводить текст, и снова блокировать.

Т.е. в простейшем случае что-то в этом роде (при нажатии на кнопку текст добавляется в текстовое поле с помощью функции `write`, но вручную отредактировать текст нельзя):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def write(text_widget, text):
    text_widget.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
    text_widget.insert(tk.END, text)
    text_widget.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)


text = tk.Text(root, state=tk.DISABLED)
text.pack()


def button_on_click():
    write(text, "Some text\n")


tk.Button(root, text="Add text", command=button_on_click).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Удобнее отнаследоваться от стандартного `Text`, и добавить отдельный метод для вывода (пусть это будет `write`, тогда виджет сможет "притворяться" файлом, и можно будет его передавать в `print` через параметр `file`, и `print` будет выводить в текстовое поле).

```
import tkinter as tk

class Report(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(state=tk.DISABLED, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def write(self, text):
        self.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.insert(tk.END, text)
        self.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

    def clear(self):
        self.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.delete(0.0, tk.END)
        self.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)


root = tk.Tk()

rep = Report(root)
rep.pack()

i = 0

def write_line():
    global i
    rep.write(f"{i}\n")
    # Или можно использовать как параметр file функции print, т.к. объект соответствует протоколу файла:
    # print(i, file=rep)
    i += 1
    root.after(100, write_line)

write_line()

tk.mainloop()
```

Для удобства также можно добавить также вертикальный сколбар, но тогда нужно отнаследоваться от фрейма, а внутри него уже добавить `Text` и `Scrollbar` (ниже только код класса, остальной код не меняется):

```
import tkinter as tk

class Report(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self._text = tk.Text(self, state=tk.DISABLED, *args, **kwargs)
        self._text.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)
        
        scrollbar['command'] = self._text.yview
        self._text['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
    
    def write(self, text):
        self._text.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self._text.insert(tk.END, text)
        self._text.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self._text.yview_moveto('1.0')  # Прокрутка до конца вниз после вывода

    def clear(self):
        self._text.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self._text.delete(0.0, tk.END)
        self._text.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
```