# Как запретить ввод, но разрешить ввыод в классе Text tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, текст

***Как запретить ввод, но разрешить ввыод в классе Text tkinter***

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.resizable(height=False, width=False)

window.option_add("*background", "black")

window.title("Консоль")

messages = Text(window, font="bold", fg="white", state=NORMAL)
messages.pack()

input_user = StringVar()
input_field = Entry(window, text=input_user, fg="white")
input_field.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)


def enter_pressed(event):
    input_get = input_field.get()
    input_get = "      [INPUT]    " + input_get
    messages.insert(INSERT, "%s\n" % input_get)
    input_user.set("")
    return "break"

frame = Frame(window)
input_field.bind("<Return>", enter_pressed)
frame.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как заблокировать виджет Text в tkinter python3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682705/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-text-%d0%b2-tkinter-python3)

Comment: у меня тот способ не сработал

Comment: @dudha369 но он рабочий (вы можете убедиться в этом, скопипастив и запустив код из ответа). Значит вы что-то не так делаете.